# Double Heston Model - Gauthier & Possamai prices

Tags: heston

has anyone successfully implemented the Double Heston model based on Fabrice Rouah's "The Heston Model and its extensions"?

I am finding that writing up the Matlab code from his chapter on the Double Heston model I am unable to match the prices he uses as examples from a paper by Gauthier & Possamai...Anyone else found the same? I am wondering if he made a typo somewhere...